# How to comment a question or an answer?

Tags: support, comments

I have started recently to use Stack Overflow. I have read the FAQ and question on this meta. I have been able to answer questions and I see how to comment on my own answers (there is an "add a comment" link), but I don't know how to comment questions or answers of others (I don't see any "add a comment" link).

Do I need some reputation to do that? Where can I find the answer?

Sorry if this appears to be evident to most of you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need 50 reputation to leave comments on other people's questions, or answers to other people's questions.

See the reputation table in the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq).

Comment: Do you know why is more expensive to comment than to answer?

Comment: @Vicente, because this is a Q & A site.  Everyone is encouraged to ask questions and give answers.  The comments are just a little extra feature to help clarify the questions and answers.  Also, you can't gain rep except by asking questions and giving answers.  So if answers required rep the only way to get rep from the beginning(1 rep) on the site would be by asking questions.

Comment: I understand that questions and answers don't need reputation, but  what is the rationale to request some reputation to help clarify the questions and answers of others? If I don't understand a question I need to request clarification before I can answer, isn't it?

Comment: @Vicente: That is a fair point; however, 50 reputation is not a heavy requirement.  It represents just 1 or 2 good questions or answers - not more than a few days of active participation, tops.  People can't downvote comments; they always appear in chronological order, so the rep requirement is the only protection the site has against trolls posting useless/offensive comments all over the place.  (The flags work too, but the diamond moderators would quickly be overwhelmed if anybody could post comments.)